# filter array content based on search criteria of input change

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have a search form that supposed to filter through a list of names that match closest to the value a user puts in .
i alreay have the value console logging mainly just having issues filtering based the the event
how do i get it to set the state to filtered state which is filtered by the event

```
handleInputChange = event => {
  console.log("new value", event.target.value);
  if (event.target.name === "search") {
    const filteredList = this.state.results.filter(item => {
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(item.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    });
    this.setState({
      filteredResults: filteredList
    })
  }
}
```

been using this example i found

```
let fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange']

  * Filter array items based on search criteria (query)
 */
 function filterItems(arr, query) {
    return arr.filter(function(el) {
  return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1
 })
  }

 console.log(filterItems(fruits, 'ap'))  // ['apple', 'grapes']
 console.log(filterItems(fruits, 'an'))  // ['banana', 'mango', 'orange']
```

Comment: what is filtered state and on which event you want to have filtered value ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what the issue is? If you want to change the state with a class based component you would use `this.setState`

Comment: Also what are you trying to do with `item.toLowerCase().indexOf(item.toLowerCase())`? That will always equate to `0`

Answer (score 0):

Don’t really understand the body of your post because I’m not a React developer but here is a vanilla JS example of searching through an array (comments added for explanation of code):

```
// this function will be called every time the input changes
function navsearch() {
    var term = document.getElementById('navsearch').value.toLowerCase()
    search(term) // initialize the search
}

function search(term) {
    var i;
    searchids = [] // set the results array to an empty state

    // loop through all possible results in the array
    for (i = 0; resources.length > i; i++) {

        // if the array items name object includes the search term, add its ID to a temporary results array
        if (resources[i].name.includes(term) == true) {
            searchids.push(resources[i].id)
        }
    }

    console.log(searchids)

    // initialize the showing of the results
    showsearchresults()
}

function showsearchresults() {
    var html = "";
    var i;

    // loop through the array holding results 
    // this will then get the name and write markup for each result
    for (i = 0; i < searchids.length; i++) {
        var html = html + `
        <div class="icon" title="${resources[searchids[i]].name}">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="${resources[searchids[i]].img}"><br><br>${resources[searchids[i]].name}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>`
    }

    // put the results on the html page
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = html
}

var searchids = [];

// possible results
var resources = [{
    id: 0,
    img: 'img/twitter.png',
    name: 'twitter'
}, {
    id: 1,
    img: 'img/discord.png',
    name: 'discord'
}, {
    id: 2,
    img: 'img/facebook.png',
    name: 'facebook'
}, {
    id: 3,
    img: 'img/instagram.png',
    name: 'instagram'
}];
```

Also a public example of this search/filtering of an array is available at http://mr-winson.github.io/brandco

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Pass your function inside onChange method.

Comment: already got that part now i just need it to filter though a table of names i have rendered